# Webform missing the bottom

Tags: html, css, webforms

I am trying to place a contact form at the bottom of my website, but the bottom of the form is sliced off. You can see a fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/qKnzp/

The code for the webform is as follows:

**CSS**

```
div.box{
margin:0 auto;
width:500px;
background:#222;
position:relative;
top:50px;
border:1px solid #262626;
}

div.box h1{ 
color:#FFF5CC;
font-size:18px;
text-transform:uppercase;
padding:5px 0 5px 5px;
border-bottom:1px solid #161712;
border-top:1px solid #161712; 
}

div.box label{
width:100%;
display: block;
background:#1C1C1C;
border-top:1px solid #262626;
border-bottom:1px solid #161712;
padding:10px 0 10px 0;
}
div.box label span{
display: block;
color:#bbb;
font-size:12px;
float:left;
width:100px;
text-align:right;
padding:5px 20px 0 0;
}

div.box .input_text{
padding:10px 10px;
width:200px;
background:#262626;
border-bottom: 1px double #171717;
border-top: 1px double #171717;
border-left:1px double #333;
border-right:1px double #333;
}

div.box .message{
padding:7px 7px;
width:350px;
background:#262626;
border-bottom: 1px double #171717;
border-top: 1px double #171717;
border-left:1px double #333;
border-right:1px double #333;
overflow:hidden;
height:150px;
}

div.box .button
{
margin:0 0 10px 0;
padding:4px 7px;
background:#CC0000;
border:0px;
position: relative;
top:10px;
left:382px;
width:100px;
border-bottom: 1px double #660000;
border-top: 1px double #660000;
border-left:1px double #FF0033;
border-right:1px double #FF0033;
}​
```

**HTML**

```
<form name="htmlform" method="post" action="html_form_send.php">
      <div class="box">
           <h1>Contact Form</h1>
                    <label>
                        <span>Full name *</span>
                        <input type="text" class="input_text" name="name" id="name"
                        />
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <span>Email *</span>
                        <input type="text" class="input_text" name="email" id="email"
                        />
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <span>Description of the product wanted *</span>
                        <input type="text" class="input_text"
                        name="subject" id="subject" />
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <span>Estimated Quantity *</span>
                        <input type="text" class="input_text" name="quantity"
                        id="quantity" />
                        <input type="submit" class="button" value="Submit Form" />
                    </label>
                </div>
```

The form should look like this:

http://aceinfowayindia.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2009/06/how-to-create-good-looking-form-without-table.html

Please could anyone explain why the bottom is missing and why the style of the forms header is different from what it should be.

Any help is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

```
#wrapper {
```

<strike>overflow: hidden;</strike>

```
}
```

Generally the code is poorly written. Learn how to write good html and css.

Comment: Thanks but it still does not fix the problem of the submit button being on the right-hand-side and the styling of the form header.